# How to analyze the network usage of processes separately in windows using java

Tags: java, jnetpcap, sigar

I am developing a java tool to gather information about network usage of processes in windows. Intention of this project is to filter out unwanted or malicious traffic. As the first step I could create a code to analyze network traffic using jpcap and jnetpcap. And to analyze process I used sigar. But no way to analyze network traffic relevant to each process.

These are the details I need for each process

- process ID
- cpu usage
- memory usage
- network usage

Except these Apis what are the APIS I can use to analyze network usage of each process.